# How to increase mdx Query speed in pentaho cde and how to clear Mondrian Schema cache

Tags: pentaho-cde

I have a problem with mdx query. Actually I developed one dashboard has 23 mdx queries. if we run these dashboard it take 2 minute to run.How to solve this problem.

Another issue

i modify some data in database.If we run these dashboard modified data isn't shown. It show previous data only.How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) 23 queries on first load may be a bit too much. Can't you simplify that? Also, are the queries all as fast as possible but it's just too many of them? Or are there slower queries that need to be improved? Check also the priority of components. You may have components rendering more than once. Example: you have a Country selector and a City selector. Because the city selector was put in befor the country selector, if they have the same priority (default=5), it'll run first, retrieving the full list of cities; Then the country selector runs and picks the first value as parameter value. As your City selector most likely listens to the Country parameter, it'll fire again because the Country was fireChange'd.

2) Cache. You're changing the data but either Mondrian or CDA (or both) are getting data from their cache. Two options here:
- Clear Mondrian cache and clear CDA cache after the data is updated (suitable for large updates that affect most of the database);
- Disable the cache on the query definition and the cube cache on the Mondrian schema.

Comment: Here there is no parameters. Direct mdx queries, they have the same priority (default=5) . How to solve issue

Comment: queries don't have priorities, only components do. Go to the advanced properties of the parameters and change their priorities so that dependent components run after primary ones.